# Are there (co-)homological obstructions to the extendability of a homomorphism?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, modules

Let $k$ be a commutative ring and $A \subset B$ an extension of $k$-algebras. Can we associate to this extension a (co-)chain complex so that its (co-)homology $H$ allows for statement such as

"Every algebra map $\varphi: A \to k$ induces a (co-)cycle in $H$ (of a certain degree) whose (co-)homology class vanishes if and only if $\varphi$ has an extension to an algebra map $B \to k$."

Can the extensions of a given $\varphi$ be classified by some (co-)homological data?

Any algebra map $\varphi: A \to k$ turns $k$ into an $A$-module such that $\varphi$ is an $A$-module map, and we can ask if $\varphi$ has an extension to an $A$-module map $B \to k$. Again my question is if there are (co-)homological obstructions to the existence of such an extension and how the extensions of a given $\varphi$ can be classified.

More generally, given an algebra map $\varphi: A \to k$ and an $A$-module $M$, is there a classification of $A$-linear maps $M \to k$ in terms of some (co-)homological data?

Comment: Wouldn't this be overpowered? If you choose $A=k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $\varphi$ the identity on the rationals, and $B$ a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra of finite type, then you would get a cohomology class who knows exactly if $\text{Spec} B$ has rational points?